# dropdown select changes back unwantedly after input is submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm using this following simplified HTML code integrated in a PHP code, which is left out.

The user can choose between two options of the dropdown selection and then enters an input to be submitted.

**The problem is that whenever clicking on the submit button after an input is entered and option2 is selected, then the dropdown selection is changed back to option1.**

Now, I want option1 to be the default when the page is first loaded, but I'd also like that **whenever option2 is selected - that it would be "anchored", that is it wouldn't be changed unless the user selects a different option** or when the page is refreshed....

Does anybody know how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

P.S - don't know if this matters but in the original code, I entered the PHP file name in the "action" attribute inside the form tag.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" >
        Category: 
        <select id="searchType" name="searchType" size="1">  
        <option value="1" class="bold-option">
        Option1
        </option>    
        <option value="2">Option2</option>   
        </select> 
        <br/>
        
        <input type="text" name="name" class="input_field" id="input_txt" dir="auto" >
        <input type="submit" value = "submit!" class="submit_button"/>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<option value="2" <?php if (isset($_POST['searchType']) && $_POST['searchType'] == "2") echo "selected"; ?> >Option2</option>` something like this?

Comment: this doesn't work for me... it changes back in the simplified and in the original code. Besides, the HTML is integrated in PHP code like this:
echo <<<_END...<html>......</html>..... _END; so your php tag proposal causes an error.

Comment: And how was we supposed to know that you post your HTML like that, when there's nothing in the code-snipped you posted that showed us that? ;-) We take code for face-value, and can't see what we can't see. But you'll get the idea of it, and can implement it, yeah?

Comment: @Qirel: first thank you for your quick response and for trying to help! since I'm new to php, I didn't know where the problem could lie on....and I didn't want to overload the question with too many details which I didn't know if they matter. but why won't we just focus on solving the problem? :)

Comment: Well, I've already given you a solution up top, and I recommend using that. But you can't use that solution inside the `echo<<<_END` kind of structure, as no logic can be put there (only direct variables). I recommend removing that structure, and just break out of PHP with `?>` instead, then entering PHP with `<?php` where needed - put your HTML in between that.

Comment: is there any other option? like using JS? I'd rather stay with this php structure at the moment and try to change it only when there is no other resort.

Comment: All you really have to do is replace `echo <<<_END` with `?>` and `_END;` with `<?php`, and you'll have what I spoke of - you can then use the suggestion I gave up top. ;)

Comment: OK it works!! many many thanks Qirel!